# Splash screen error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Necesito hacer una pantalla de inicio para una aplicación Java, pero incluso siguiendo los pasos de los tutoriales de Internet, no puedo hacer que funcione bien.
Me gustaría que la pantalla de inicio fuera de color verde y luego el logotipo de la aplicación en el medio. El problema es que solo me sale el fondo verde, o si cambio el orden de los elementos en splash_screen.xml, la foto con fondo negro. En el .xml me sale la siguiente advertencia:
[image: .xml warning]

He intentado poner diferentes tamaños y tipos de imágenes, e incluso los ic_launchers que vienen por defecto en @mipmap, pero no hay forma de que funcione. ¡Vamos a ver si alguien me puede ayudar! Adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora. ¡Gracias!

splash_screen.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/imagen"/>
    
        </item>
        
    </selector>
```

themes.xml

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.CookPad" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>
    
        <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.CookPad">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        </style>


</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#9CDEB3</color>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.mondragon.cookpad">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CookPad">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Cocinero"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Camarero"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity onCreate function

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
    
            }
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_CookPad);
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        {
```

Demotración de lo que pasa: splash_screen.xml

```
 <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/imagen"/>

    </item>
```

[image: First item, color; Second item, image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/imagen"/>

    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>

</selector>
```

[image: First item, image; Second item,color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define dentro de `/drawable` y usa un `layer-list` en lugar de un `selector`, aquì tambièn puedes definir la imagen, muy importante que esta imagen se encuentre también dentro de `/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:top="-48dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Dentro de styles.xml define el archivo splash_screen.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Este estilo definelo a tu Activity dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
   <activity
            android:name="SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        </activity>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma tu Activity podrá mostra el fondo con el color deseado incluyendo tu imagen

---

Dentro de tu Activity no necesitas definir algún thread.sleep() u otro estilo

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            /*try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
    
            }
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_CookPad);*/
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        {
```

Comment: Hola Jorge! Muchisimas gracias por haberme ayudado y solucionado el problema. Ya funciona correctamente!!

Comment: Excelente , no olvides marcar la respuesta como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He visto una diferencia con una que a mi me funciona ; cambia en temas.xml:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.CookPad">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
 </style>
```

por

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.CookPad">
    <item name="background">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
´´´
```

Comment: Hola! He pobado a cambiar eso peor ahora lo que pasa es que el splash_screen sale blanco. Aun asi, muchas gracias por molestarte y ayudarme!

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Una buena respuesta, además de código debería aportar una explicación de por qué o cómo soluciona el problema indicado. Intentamos que las respuestas sirvan para algo más que copiar y pegar sin entender nada, si no también para que podamos entender el origen/causa del problema y cual es la solución adecuada! Cuanto mejor explicado, más gente lo comprenderá y más útil será la respuesta. Te recomiendo leer [answer] para entender como elaborar una mejor respuesta.